# Add Google Calendar into an activity on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Is there a way to add Google Calendar into an activity on the Android App? Actually I tried to use CalendarView, but it does not have option to add event and display it on the particular date unlike Google Calendar.

I don't like to use Caldroid or someother libraries as it does not look like standalone Google Calendar App on Android.

Eventually I would like to display events in the format of either event title or different bg colors on the day/date column on the calendar. In case of different colors, the list of events can be displayed when user clicks the day/date.

Will Google provide API for Android in future to add the calendar with event into the activity and highlighting event on the calendar?

Comment: There is already a Google Calendar API. As for displaying events, there's a handful of libraries here  https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27